# Negative polytropic index

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, astrophysics

A polytrope is a relation between the pressure and the density of the form
$$P\sim \rho^\gamma\equiv\rho^{1+1/n}$$
where $n$ is usually referred as the "polytropic index" and in principle could vary in $-\infty\leq n\leq +\infty.$ Physically, what does it mean to have a system with $n<-1$?

This is: $0\leq\gamma<1$.

Answer (score 1):

It would mean you have a very "soft" equation of state, where your gas or material is rather easy to compress. If $\gamma=0$ it means the pressure does not increase as you compress the gas. This can't be arranged in an adiabatic system - reducing the volume at constant pressure requires it to be cooled at the same time.